# Grouping Numpy Array and Returning Minimum Values

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a ndarray like this:

```
data = [(1,"YES", 54.234), 
         (1,"YES", 1.0001), 
         (2,"YES", 4.234),
         (3,"YES", 0.234)]
dtypes = [("GROUPID", np.int), 
          ("HASNEAR", "|S255"), 
          ("DISTANCE", np.float64)]
array = np.array(data, dtype=dtypes)
```

Is there a way to group the data and return only the Minimum distance in each group in a new array?

In my example, I have 4 rows.  After the group and return minimum, I would expect only 3 rows returned. One for each GROUPID value.

If numpy arrays aren't the right tool, could you do this in Pandas?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a pandas DataFrame, group by GROUPID and aggregate by `min()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=('GROUPID','HASNEAR','DISTANCE'))
df.groupby('GROUPID').min()
```

Answer (score 2):

AS illustrated by others, you can do this in pandas, but it is a relatively heavyweight abstraction that introduces all kinds of other complexities that you may or may not be interested in.

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package specializes in these kind of operations in isolation:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
npi.group_by(data['GROUPID']).min(data['DISTANCE'])
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can do this in pandas:

```
In [8]:
import pandas as pd
# construct a df
df = pd.DataFrame(array)
df

Out[8]:
   GROUPID HASNEAR  DISTANCE
0        1  b'YES'   54.2340
1        1  b'YES'    1.0001
2        2  b'YES'    4.2340
3        3  b'YES'    0.2340
```

You can now `groupby` on GROUPID column, call `idxmin` to return the index of the min value for the column of interest and use this to filter the orig df:

```
In [9]:
df.loc[df.groupby('GROUPID')['DISTANCE'].idxmin()]

Out[9]:
   GROUPID HASNEAR  DISTANCE
1        1  b'YES'    1.0001
2        2  b'YES'    4.2340
3        3  b'YES'    0.2340
```

You can see what `idxmin` returns is the index of the min values:

```
In [10]:
df.groupby('GROUPID')['DISTANCE'].idxmin()

Out[10]:
GROUPID
1    1
2    2
3    3
Name: DISTANCE, dtype: int64
```

You can convert back to a numpy array by calling `.values`:

```
In [11]:
df.loc[df.groupby('GROUPID')['DISTANCE'].idxmin()].values

Out[11]:
array([[1, b'YES', 1.0001],
       [2, b'YES', 4.234],
       [3, b'YES', 0.234]], dtype=object)
```